# iOS Swift How to get value of any key from json response

Tags: ios, json, swift, key-value

I am getting a response from an API

```
["response": {
    record =     {
        title = "Order Add";
        usercart = 5345;
    };
}, "status": success, "message": تم إضافة السجل بنجاح]
```

I got the Value for status Key from the code

```
let statusCode = json["status"].string
```

Now i want the value for the key usercart in string value
I am using this code but getting any response.

```
let order_id = json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].string
```

Please help me to get this value.

Comment: `usercart` could be also an integer. I recommend to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: how to get this value and convert it into int

Comment: I’m not that familiar with `SwiftyJSON`. Use code completion. Probably it’s `int` or `integer`.

Comment: @vadian ```SwiftyJSON``` automatically convert int to string.

Comment: use ```json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].stringValue```. insted of ```string``` use ```stringValue```

Comment: @RajaKishan thanks it works. If you post this as answer i will mark your answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `SwiftyJSON` and you are trying to get `usercart` value as a `string` but the `usercart` is `Int`.

So if you want this in string formate you should need to use `.stringValue` instead of `.string` else you can use `.int` or `.intValue` in form of `int`.

```
json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].stringValue
```

Answer (score 2):

The json you are getting from server is wrong. Instead it should be -

```
["response": {
    "record" : {
        "title" : "Order Add",
        "usercart" : 5345
    };
}, "status": success, "message": تم إضافة السجل بنجاح]
```

There is nothing like **=** in json

Also if server response cannot change I would suggest reading this whole thing as string and then using search in string, though it is very bad approach.

Comment: how to fetch usercart value?

Comment: If the server sends the correct json like above then let order_id = json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].string this would work

Comment: json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].stringValue solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

if you are using SwiftyJSON then use this to get value

```
  json["response"]["record"]["usercart"].stringValue
```

Comment: this ans is already posted. Is there anything new?